Error: Command failed with UNKNOWN: next -p 8888 renderer
I have been working on this project for a few months now and everything was great. I paused working on it for 2 months, and today when I try to run the development server using the command npm run dev or try building the app using the command npm run build I am greeted with the below error. Do you have any idea about what could fix it?  I already tried deleting the node_modules folder and running npm install, but it did not work.
The error message:
Error: Command failed with UNKNOWN: next -p 8888 renderer
spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:421:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:761:9)
    at execa (A:\Work\DigiCrafterz\my-apa\apa-patient-new-design\apa-patient-desktop\apa-patient-electron\node_modules\execa\index.js:83:26)
    at A:\Work\DigiCrafterz\my-apa\apa-patient-new-design\apa-patient-desktop\apa-patient-electron\node_modules\nextron\bin\nextron-dev.js:2:3970
    at A:\Work\DigiCrafterz\my-apa\apa-patient-new-design\apa-patient-desktop\apa-patient-electron\node_modules\nextron\bin\nextron-dev.js:2:4068
    at Object.<anonymous> (A:\Work\DigiCrafterz\my-apa\apa-patient-new-design\apa-patient-desktop\apa-patient-electron\node_modules\nextron\bin\nextron-dev.js:2:4283) 
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn',
  originalMessage: 'spawn UNKNOWN',
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with UNKNOWN: next -p 8888 renderer\nspawn UNKNOWN',
  command: 'next -p 8888 renderer',
  escapedCommand: 'next -p 8888 renderer',
  exitCode: undefined,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: '',
  stderr: '',
  all: '',
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}

Node.js v20.11.0`
